# SSL certs for a number of docker container services on a single host

Tags: docker, letsencrypt

I'm very new to Docker, but I've successfully set up a `docker-compose.yaml` consisting of a handful of services like Mosquitto, NodeRED, InfluxDB, and Grafana. Each publishes an HTTP endpoint on a different port. These all work well locally.

Now I want to move them to a host in the cloud, but Safari requires all HTTP connections to be HTTPS/TLS, so I need to set up certs for everything. From what I can gather, I think I have two options:

1. Configure each service individually to use SSL certs. I can probably have them all reference the same cert placed on a volume shared among the services in docker-compose.
2. Maybe set up nginx as a proxy for each of these? It would be yet another service in docker-compose, forwarding connections on ports on its container to ports on the other containers.

I'm not sure which one of these approaches is better. Because it's Let’s Encrypt, the certs need to be renewed often.

My googling on the matter has turned up few direct solutions; I would have thought this was a more common problem, but maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

On both approaches you will need a different implementation ; But I will prefer the classic one :

**NGINX** :

```
    Generate a server certificate ( Used by the 4 apps )

    You will need to create 1 Vhost for every app.

    Map the exposed ports to the Vhosts on docker-compose

    Use of certbot for auto renewal  on your docker-compose.
```

*CONS*:

```
  You  will have a single entry to your apps ( **Single point of failure** )

  The communication between your NGINX Reverse Proxy and your containers will not be **secured**.
```

*PROS*: Fast implementation

**Classic** :

```
    Generate a server certificate ( Used by the 4 apps )

    Setup SSL differently on every app configuration file.

    Use of certbot for auto renewal on your docker-compose.
```

*PROS*: Slow implementation

Comment: I would like to follow the "classic" approach, but am struggling because many services/libraries will verify the host of the certificate, forcing me to generate different ones with their own "CN" values. How would you solve this? Could I, for instance, somehow assign the same hostname to multiple Docker Compose services?